# pass data to component dynamically

Tags: angular, ionic3

I would transfer the data from one component to the other dynamically.
When I change the ShowParent value in the addPrelevement method, the showParent value changes, but the child component does not reconfigure this change
this is the first component
html:

```
<page-prelevement>
      <page-progress-bar   [(showChild)] ="showParent" ></page-progress-bar>
</page-prelevement>
```

ts:

```
export class PrelevementPage {
ShowParent: boolean= true;
constructor(....)
}
addPrelevement(){
this.ShowParent=false;
}
```

the child component:

```
export class ProgressBarPage 
{
   @Input() showChild: boolean;
  constructor(....) {
    console.log(this.showChild+   "show child");
  }
```

html of child Component

```
<div class="progress-outer">
  <div  *ngIf="showChild" [@myAnimation] class="progress-inner" ></div>
</div>
```

How to solve this problem? Or is there another way to do it?

Comment: I'd start by using camelCase in a consistent way, and thus use `showParent` everywhere, instead of using `ShowParent` sometimes, and `showParent` some other times. Then, if it doesn't fix the problem, I'd post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, with a link to a plunkr where we can see it in action and debug it.

Comment: preset your input property in your child component. `@Input showChild: boolean = false;`. And `[(showChild)] ="showParent"` should probably be `[showChild]="ShowParent"`. TBH im not so sure about presetting is the issue, it is with strings, but with booleans, i would have to try.

Comment: i use  @Input() showChild: boolean =false; and recheck showParent.. nothing change.

Comment: As@JBNizet said, change the variable name in your `component` to `showParent` instead of `ShowParent`. JS is CaSe-SeNsiTivE.

Comment: I found a solution. I add setTimeout in the constructor of progress-bar component.   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
setTimeout(() => {
  this.showChild=false;
    }, );
  }